# ls -lrt showing file which is not present

Tags: linux, filesystems, symbolic-link

When I do `ls -lart` in my current working directory it shows

`lrwxrwxrwx   1 root 10004    36 Dec 16 17:59 index.html ->/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/index.html`

But I cannot see contents of the file.And most important the file `index.html` is not present in the path `/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/`.
Then why it is showing up when I run command `ls -lrt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). How do I know?

First letter suggest that: **l** rwxrwxrwx

If you don't need this link any more than just remove it using `rm -f`

Answer (score 2):

The `index.html` symbolic link in your current directory is there, however the file it points to is not.

Symbolic links are essentially just files which point programs trying to access them to a different file. However, the symbolic link has no way of knowing whether the file it points to is actually there, so you sometimes get symbolic links that point to non-existent files, in the same way that weblinks sometimes point to a web page that no longer exists

You will have to recreate the target file at `/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/index.html`, or alternatively you may delete the link using `rm`.